# Laravel - Cannot send a php POST request WITHOUT ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have this really really strange problem and went through all over the web for a solution.

I have used AJAX so far for all of my API needs, but I would like to make a simple php form request without ajax this time, and I strangely can't. It just shows a GET request in the URL and a blank page, though the url looks like:

```
www.webpage.com/api/articles/POST?_token=GNnbqgcGinEFTXMWtBbWdpDMdqBip99wa9XNTq71&title=bla&body=bla
```

I'm using Laravel's REST API so i'm using the same url for post and get `Route::resource`, though POST requests doesn't work with other routes as well. GET works fine, though post, update and delete works as get (doesn't work) and i'm battling this for hours, not knowing why it receives well with ajax but not with a direct php call. :\

Much thanks for any helpers!

Comment: Can you show your two routes that you're using... or the one you might be using...

Comment: It's the same one as above, www.webpage.com/api/articles, though the post request doesn't work even with a different route so I doubt it has something to do with REST... :\

Comment: ... Not what I'm asking... I mean you have `Route::post('api/articles/POST', ...)` AND `Route::get('api/articles/POST', ...)`?

Comment: Oh sorry, i'm using a resource so it generates the routes... but yeah, all gets are working fine just all others don't...

Comment: Ok! That's what I wanted to make sure. :D Go ahead and add that in to the question.

Comment: Alright hehe... :) Though I doubt it has something to do with the resource since when sending the request via angular it works great!

Comment: Is there anything in your log file which might give a hint?  Is `/api/articles/POST` really a route you have?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I wish I had some kind of log to provide... It could've help me solve it. Is there any other way to log it besides laravel.log in storage folder? Apache and PHP logs doesn't say anything about it, neither does laravel's... :\ and yes it is really a route, it just skips any post/put/delete route requests, and shows a url get request with an empty page, though it works well using ajax! which is why it's so confusing :\

Comment: Thanks for reaching out both of ya, I feel so stupid right now.... But at least I got it working! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was a major GOOBER! I should be quite ashamed, but i'm used to ajax calls and APIs for so long that I forgot how a simple HTML form request looks like.

I putted the method in the action tag and the action in href. :D

That's why I got the url string as get, and it never processed it... It was a get request all along...

Thanks for all the hassle, be happy and prosper. :) (And don't make silly mistakes like I do!)